# Webview Pagination effect

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I have large `HTML` file loaded into a `WebView`. I want to add a pagination effect to the `WebView`, so the user can scroll horizontally.

```
if(HeightWv == 0) {
    contentHts= 0;
}  else if (HeightWv!=0) {
    contentHts= HeightWv;
}

HeightWv = webview.getHeight();
Log.e("1",""+ HeightWv);
HeightWv = HeightWv+contentHts;
Log.e("2",""+ HeightWv);                        
webview.scrollTo(0, HeightWv);
```

When using above code, the content is hidden on the top of the screen. Can anyone help me with `WebView` Pagination, please?

Comment: I'm developing an Android application that reads ebooks (in epub format) and as for now I'm using Paul Siegeman's epublib library that is really a very good epub reader but it has some limitations, for example and the one I need, you can't move through pages horizontally (as you do reading a real book) so I need my own implementation of it, but I'm stuck.

Comment: can any one guide me and share ideas Webview pagination horizontal scroll android

Answer (score -2):

If you're writing an ebook reader - you'd better use ViewPager instead of WebView. As for WebView - I really doubt that there is a way of implementing pagination by means of Android - you'll have to write some JavaScript

Comment: why would you "better use viewpager" instead of webview? Epubs have html - it's easier to display this via a webview no?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to give a short answer to that. I don't say that you can't do that - this is definitely possible but that's not a native way of doing this. Therefore, in order to properly implement this type of functionality one has to do a lot of extra and unnecessary work (implementing pagination and View recycling in JS) when everything is already there in the SDK. Moreover, WebViews are very slow compared to conventional Views and they are not supposed to host the entire app.

Comment: Hmm, but faster than textviews unless you're suggesting something else? http://www.hidroh.com/2016/02/27/richtext-textview-versus-webview/ . Doesnt have to host entire app though, just the book view?

Comment: With ViewPager hosting TextViews you do not need to render the whole book at once. Moreover, I have to say that the link you provided does not use the pagination - because of that you may notice increased memory consumption. In case of a ViewPager you only hold 3 pages in memory (current, next and previous and this behavior is configurable) and the rest are rendered on demand with a buffered reader reading the text file. WebViews are good when you want to connect your app to some webpage but I honestly believe that they are not supposed to be used as core elements.

Comment: @Chaosit Can you suggest a tutorial where I can learn on how to read epub files into view pager?

Comment: @Chaosit Don't you lose formatting (like bold, bullets, images) if you convert the Html data into string using `Html.fromHtml()` method to display it in text view?

Comment: @SrikarReddy according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler)) you get Spanned as a return value of `Html.fromHtml()` and technically Span comes in different flavors including bulleting, styling and images. To be completely honest I've never had to work with laying out the HTML file (usually I had to add span to the text depending on the data received in JSON or XML format).

Comment: @SrikarReddy anyway for these purposes [this package](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html) is your friend. Regarding the tutorial - haven't worked with this kind of issues before, however, googling suggests [this](https://github.com/mertakdut/EpubParser). But what I personally don't like about this library is that it returns you the String - not the Spanned object. Which means that you'll have to do some post-processing afterwards. And I also have to mention that my Android knowledge may now be a bit outdated as I quit Android development 2 years ago